# Does a technical umbrella term exist that covers the different kinds of biomolecules?

Tags: biochemistry, terminology

I want to write a sentence along the lines of:

> There are four ____ in biochemistry: proteins, lipids, carbohydrates and nucleic acids.

Does a specific technical term exist that I can use to fill the void? Or am I relatively free in my choice?

Comment: Refer to them like what? Group or type of chemical compounds? Why not? You're asking about basic semantics...

Comment: Yes, I want to write a sum about the topic but I don't know the terminology.  Refer to them like groups. I mean to ask if I can divide the main biochemical molecules to 4 families.

Comment: Well, they are already divided - these **are** 4 groups of compounds. Group or type is better word then family here IMO, but what's here to ask about...

Comment: Are they the only groups of compound in biochemistry?

Comment: "Classes of biomolecules".

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what your background is. Maybe it is organic chemistry, where the term *functional group* is used in a very specific way and using what would seem to be a synonym instead is wrong. Maybe it is biology (taxonomy) where it makes a big difference if a ‘group’ is an order, a family, a genus or something else.

The typical primary metabolites in biochemistry — carbohydrates, peptides/proteins, nucleic acids and lipids — do not have an overarching, widely accepted technical umbrella term. You can call them *groups, classes, kinds* or even *types* and be well understood.

If I had to suggest something, I would go with *classes of primary metabolites.* But I wouldn’t call that a strict technical term like *functional group* (organic chemistry) or *species* (taxonomy).

Answer (score 1):

Adding on to what Jan mentioned I looked it up in a few of the well-known textbooks. (Emphasis mine.)

Alberts et al. *Molecular Biology of the Cell* 6ed, p47 writes

> "**four major families of small organic molecules**"

Berg & Stryer *Biochemistry* 7ed, p2 is a bit more careful

> [...] two different **classes of molecules**: large molecules such as proteins and nucleic acids, referred to as biological macromolecules, and low-molecular-weight molecules such as glucose and glyccerol, referred to as metabolites [...]

Lehninger *Principles of Biochemistry* 6ed, p15 writes

> Many biological molecules are macromolecules... shorter polymers are called oligomers... Table 1-1 shows the **major classes of biomolecules** in an *E. coli* cell. [Entries in Table 1-1: Water, proteins, nucleic acids, polysaccharides, lipids, monomeric subunits and intermediates, inorganic ions.]

Voet & Voet *Biochemistry* 4ed, p15 writes

> [...] *E. coli*, and living things in general, contain only a few different types of macromolecules: proteins, [...] nucleic acids, and polysaccharides. [...] Lipids, the fourth **major class of biological molecules**, are too small to be classified as macromolecules but also have a modular construction.

---

Two weeks ago I suggested "classes of biomolecules" in my comment. In lieu of what I have quoted above, I think that might be a little bit imprecise since there are more types of biomolecules than simply those four classes. So, **"major classes of biomolecules"** would be a good idea.